# file /proc/kcore took up all free space in the system and and it won't let you install programs

Tags: linux, kali-linux, proc

I have Kali linux OS. When I try install `dkms` I have got this:

```
└─# sudo apt install dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dctrl-tools
Suggested packages:
  menu
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dctrl-tools dkms
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 565 not upgraded.
Need to get 161 kB of archives.
After this operation, 632 kB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

All this cause of all free space was taken by this file.
When I query the properties of my system and I get: `Usage:0 bytes of 24.6 GiB free (100% used)`.
`du -shx *` run from the root directory shows:

```
└─# du -shx *
0       0
0       bin
0       boot
0       dev
364K    etc
3.1M    home
0       initrd.img
0       initrd.img.old
0       lib
0       lib32
0       lib64
0       libx32
8.0K    media
0       mnt
0       opt
du: cannot access 'proc/339706/task/339706/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/339706/task/339706/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/339706/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/339706/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0       proc
324K    root
1.5M    run
0       sbin
0       srv
0       sys
276K    tmp
8.5M    usr
1.2M    var
0       vmlinuz
0       vmlinuz.old
```

Size of kcore file equals `128.0 TiB (140,737,471,590,400 bytes)`.

When I measure size of all directories except proc dir I get :`69024 items, totalling 1.2 GiB (1,280,074,564 bytes) (some contents unreadable)`.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`/proc/kcore`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) isn’t at fault here. All the contents of `/proc` are virtual files which don’t take any space on your disk; they provide access to various pieces of information made available by the kernel. `/proc/kcore` in particular represents the entire address space, which is why it’s 128TiB in size.

Your disk space is occupied by something else. You might be able to clean some unnecessary files by running

```
apt autoclean
```

or even

```
apt clean
```

(the latter may result in files being re-downloaded for a later `apt install`).

Failing that, [Find largest files recursively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55616/86440) should help you find large files which you might be able to delete (*e.g.* log files under `/var/log`). Take care not to delete files belonging to packages or containing important data.

Comment: I tried this commands, but it doesn't help me. I understand that disk space occupied by something, but how can I find their ?

Comment: Always thought kcore' size was size of the physical memory used plus 4 KB. ??

Comment: @MC68020 so what, it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @MC68020 I think that’s the case on 32-bit systems, but on 64-bit systems it’s the size of the kernel’s address space, plus the ELF header. (I’d love to have a system with 128TiB of RAM — actually maybe not, it would be physically quite large.)

Comment: @Stephen Kitt Thank you very much, I found large files in `var/log` directory. But I'm surprised that the `du -shx *` command returns a `log` folder size of `56K`, but logs already appear inside with sizes of `9.9G`. why is that?

Comment: That depends on where you ran it from, and what your mounted file systems are. Feel free to ask a new question if you want to explore further, or search the size for `du`-related questions (there are already a lot).

Comment: @Stephen Kitt Okey,thank you very much

Comment: @DmitriyOgureckiy If you're looking at the output of things like `ls -l /var/log/lastlog` you will have to take into account this this is a sparse file. `du -h lastlog` will give you the actual size on disk of the files.

Comment: Compare the output of `du -h /var/log/lastlog` with `du -h --apparent-size /var/log/lastlog` to see how sparse files appear to be big when they are not.